# getting started with websphere application server

Tags: websphere

Am a java programmer and wanted to get started with Websphere Application server. 
Can someone please suggest some good intro. books/articles/links etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM's red books are good resources to start and there is another article on IBM developers work.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0305_issw/recommendedreading.html

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247304.html

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246451.html